# Loading images from a url is scaled way too large

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using a UITableView to load in images from a url. It actually works great and scales everything appropriately. However, when I do the same within a UIScrollView, all the images are even scaled larger than I had made them. The images are meant for the retina display, but I was hoping it would scale down for older screens. But, at this point, it looks wrong in all screens.

Any ideas? What is the proper way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check both the scale factor of your `UIScrollView`, and the contentMode of the `UIImageView` you uses to display your image?

Are the `size` property of the `UIImage` coherent with the size you expect the image to be?

Comment: Im not sure. All I did was set my UIImageView frame size to the low res dimensions and hoping it would scale automatically

Comment: ah the problem was that I used imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;